# AWS Cognito - Verify email account, then require administrator approval for account activation

Tags: amazon-cognito

With an AWS Cognito User Pool, there is:
"Self Service Sign-up"

Can I interject an administrator approval after the email is verified but before the account is approved/active?

Or if I check Self Service Sign Up off, is there a way to send an email verification, get this confirmed, and then require an administrator to approve the account?

Please pardon the broad question.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes according to this but it doesn't really say how, see "Allowing users to sign up in your app but confirming them as administrator" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html

Comment: Hello, nice document. See the problem is there. You can EITHER have admin confirm, OR email confirm (in that diagram). But what I'm looking for is email confirm, THEN admin confirm. Right?

Comment: The diagram is not what suggests to me that it is possible but rather points 1 - 4 in the text section "Allowing users to sign up in your app but confirming them as administrator" seems to suggest to me that they get email verified but are in a pending state waiting for admin confirmation. That's how i'm reading that text. I'd like to implement it too but that text has not helped me figure out how.